# WebPack failing due to typescript errors in angular2/universal

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, webpack

I am currently having trouble using webpack hot module reloading working. I can successfully run an angular2 page, but if I go to the html file, change content, then save, it gives me a list of typescript errors and doesn't update the page. A full page refresh will update the page, but I want it to be automatic, as was intended with webpack. My sample application is on github here: [Snazzle sample app](https://github.com/tonywr71/Snazzle). Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

```
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(12,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(12,25): error TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(17,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(17,22): error TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(20,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(20,22): error TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(21,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(21,23): error TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(12,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(17,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(12,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(20,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(12,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(21,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(20,24): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'boolean'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(21,25): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'boolean'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(12,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'platformRef'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(17,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'injector'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(20,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'disposed'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.d.ts
(21,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'destroyed'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(1,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(28,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(28,20): error TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(63,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(63,20): error TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(64,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(64,18): error TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(63,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(64,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(63,22): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'string'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(64,20): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'string'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(28,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'origin'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(63,14): error TS2663: Cannot find name 'search'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.search'?
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-location.d.ts
(64,14): error TS2663: Cannot find name 'hash'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.hash'?
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\ClientApp\boot-server.ts
(6,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Tony/Source/Repos/Snazzle/Snazzle.UI/node_modules/angular2-universal/common/index"' has no exported member 'BASE_URL'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\ClientApp\boot-server.ts
(6,20): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Tony/Source/Repos/Snazzle/Snazzle.UI/node_modules/angular2-universal/common/index"' has no exported member 'ORIGIN_URL'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\ClientApp\boot-server.ts
(6,32): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Tony/Source/Repos/Snazzle/Snazzle.UI/node_modules/angular2-universal/common/index"' has no exported member 'REQUEST_URL'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\ClientApp\boot-server.ts
(10,32): error TS2339: Property 'bootloader' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/Users/Tony/Source/Repos/Snazzle/Snazzle.UI/node_modules/angular2-universal/typings"'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Tony\Source\Repos\Snazzle\Snazzle.UI\ClientApp\boot-server.ts
(19,31): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Tony/Source/Repos/Snazzle/Snazzle.UI/node_modules/angular2-universal/typings"' has no exported member 'AppConfig'.
```